# How to allow location in Gecko driver always or a website on Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, geolocation, location

Hi I want to allow location always or a specific website but I couldn't solve my problem.

right now I open the page informations and set it manually but I want to do it programmatically.

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('Path'
                          '-1602622171076')
fp.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp, executable_path='Path')
driver.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

1.For Chrome :

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# to accept all the notifications

opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
opt.add_argument("start-maximized")
opt.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1,
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1
})
```

its a code to accept all the notifications

> 1 means agree
>
> 0 means disable

if you want to disable any just replace 1 with 0

2. For Mozilla firefox :

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()

options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", True)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
```

Comment: Options doesn't include add_experimental_options first I got this error and changed to preferences it still gives error __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Options', I added opt to my driver as Options=opt

Comment: Import this :from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

Comment: It still doesn't work cause first problem is "opt.add_experimental_option";
could you review the all your answer because there are differences like options = Options()

I tried some way but it doesn't work if there is a chance could you try it ?

Comment: i added mozilla firefox code too in solution,try that